# DKIM and subdomains

Tags: email, dkim

We use a sub domain "mail.domain.com" for sending marketing emails from Salesforce Marketing Cloud, the reason it was set up this way is to keep the reputation of this domain separate from our normal domain "domain.com".

All of the links within the mail headers point to "mail.domain.com", except for the From: field which contains the user's mail address on our primary domain "domain.com".

Currently we are failing DKIM because the From: field is domain.com and DKIM is expecting the From: header to be mail.domain.com.

What is the suggested set up for this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Just add another DKIM TXT record for your subdomain and add the DKIM signature to it like this:

```
TX      abc._domainkey         v=DKIM1; lorem ipsum;
TX      abc._domainkey.mail    v=DKIM1; lorem ipsum;
```

I would recommend you add separate SPF and DMARC records for your subdomain as well. They should look something like this:

DMARC:

```
TX    _dmarc         v=DMARC1; lorem ipsum;
TX    _dmarc.mail    v=DMARC1; lorem ipsum;
```

SPF:

```
TX    @       v=spf1 ip4:12.34.56.789 -all;
TX    mail    v=spf1 ip4:12.34.56.789 -all;
```

Comment: Of these, DMARC is inherited from the parent, and doesn't need another record unless the policy is different.